# matrix2png installation in MAC OSX and libpng-1.6.17

Tags: macos, libpng

I'm trying to install `matrix2png`.

So, I have installed `libpng` using Homebrew.

But, when I type `./configure` to install `matrix2png`, the following error message comes up:

> You need to have libpng installed and findable by the configure script

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
brew info libpng
```

to see where `libpng` is installed.

**Sample Output**

```
libpng: stable 1.6.17 (bottled)
Library for manipulating PNG images
http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.16 (17 files, 1.3M)
  Poured from bottle
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.17 (17 files, 1.2M) *
```

Then try running

```
./configure --help
```

to see how to add a parameter to `./configure` to tell it where to find `libpng` now that you know that from the first step. As a *pure* guess, you'll probably need something along the lines of

```
./configure --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.16/lib
```